# Apache2 has errors while starting after reinstalling SSL Certificate?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, ssl-certificate, ubuntu-12.04

I recently purchased and set up a VPS, and one of the first steps I took was to purchase and install an SSL Certificate.  I had issues getting everything set up, but after quite a bit of research and head pounding it was finally set up correctly.  I had a rewrite in the .htaccess file that forced https connections.  Everything was sunshine and lolly-pops.  Then came heartbleed!

I had my SSL certificate reissued, and created new private keys.  I then followed [these steps](http://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/pem-ssl-creation.htm) to create a chained file.  Now, when I try to start apache2, I'm getting the following error:

```
[Mon Apr 28 10:32:59 2014] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `example.com' does NOT match server name!?
[Mon Apr 28 10:32:59 2014] [error] Unable to configure RSA server private key
[Mon Apr 28 10:32:59 2014] [error] SSL Library Error: 185073780 error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch
```

What exactly does that mean?  The certificate was just reissued, so there shouldn't have been any changes to the server name.  Did I flub making the chain file?

**Other Information**

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, with Apache 2.2.22.  Oddness:  I updated OpenSSL, and had no issues, prior to reissuing the cert.  Now `openssl version` returns "OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012".  Furthermore, I went to [this checker](https://filippo.io/Heartbleed/) and [this checker](https://lastpass.com/heartbleed/) after setting everything back up, and got a clean bill of health for both.  However, I don't think I ever restarted apache after changing the certificates.

Thoughts, advice, and guidance are appreciated!

**Update**

In my `default-ssl` I have it pointing to the following:

```
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/developingawesomeness.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/developingawesomeness.com.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/developingawesomeness.com.chain.pem
```

Those files are in those directories as well.

Comment: You have correctly updated both the certificate file and the keyfile, yes?  I'm a bit suspicious about the way you say "*I had my SSL certificate reissued, and created new private keys"*; you didn't really do it in that order, did you?

Comment: `I had my SSL certificate reissued, and created new private keys.` In that order? That sounds like you crated a CSR with the old key and then switched the private key to a new one.

Comment: That might be it, but I'm pretty sure I misspoke on that.  I used `openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout server.key -out server.csr` to generate a new csr, and used that to get the new cert.

Comment: Is there a way to check the common name on the csr to verify that it matches the actual domain name?

Comment: Open the chain file in `vi` and check for invisible characters. `:set list`

Comment: Also, are you sure that your Apache configuration is set to look at the proper file(s) in the `SSLCertificateFile` and `SSLCertificateKeyFile` directives?

Comment: There are `$` immediately after each EOL.  As it should be?

Comment: Yes, a `$` is what is expected. If there's nothing else, then that should mean it's fine.

Comment: Yes, updated the question to show where the directives are pointing.  Also verified that those files are indeed in that directory.

Comment: To see the embedded CN (and more), do `openssl x509 -in server.crt -noout -text`.

Comment: Sounds like you got a new certificate with a new CSR but you never changed the CSR on the server.

Comment: That might have been it.  I just removed everything in `/etc/apache2/ssl`, generated a new `csr` and went from there.  Went smooth, considering the rough time I had when I did it the first time.  Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the issue was exactly, but I created yet another `csr` and had my certificate re-reissued.  Comodo actually sent different files than they had previously.  Starting from scratch and chaining the necessary files fixed the issue.

Answer (score -1):

problem was private key. In apache server, if you create private key with passphrase then server will not start properly.